# Create a new color vector for each unique factor in a vector based of another predefined vector.

Tags: r

Apologies because I don't know how to phrase this question. Suppose have a two vectors

```
v <- c("a","a","a","a",'b','b')
color <- c("red","yellow")
```

without manaually assigning the color to each unique element

```
final.color <- c("red","red","red","red","red","yellow","yellow")
```

how can I automatically create this vector?

thanks.

Comment: `as.character(factor(v,labels=color))`  or `setNames(color, unique(v))[v]` - i'm sure this has to be a duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

First we find the number of unique elements in `v` then use `rep` to re-create `final.color`

```r
v <- c("a","a","a","a",'b','b')
color <- c("red","yellow")

final.color <- c("red","red","red","red","yellow","yellow")

# find number of unique elements in a vector
n_unique <- c(table(v))

# create color from n_unique
tmp <- c(rep(color[1], n_unique[1]), rep(color[2], n_unique[2]))
tmp
#> [1] "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "yellow" "yellow"

identical(final.color, tmp)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thanks I modified it a bit more, 
`v <- c("a","a","a","a",'b','b')
color <- c("red","yellow")

nu <- data.frame(table ( v) ) 
nc <- c()
for ( i in 1:nrow (nu)){
  nc <- c( nc, rep ( color[i], nu[i,]$Freq ) )
}

nc`

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use `for` loop and where did `$Freq` come from?

Comment: the for loop is so that without manually entering color[x] since in other instances there could be more, I can generate the final.color.  Thanks the table idea is clever.